# Why Entity Framework Core 2.2 FirstOrDefaultAsync method not found?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, sqlite, asp.net-core-webapi

I am making an Web Application with the following -

1. ASP.NET Core
2. Entity Framework Core
3. SQlite Database
4. Angular SPA (ng 7)

I have made a model named User with some properties like below -

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
}
```

What I have chosen is model first approach and migrate data to create table accordingly

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

But whenever I am trying to find a user with the following -

```
public async Task<User> Login(string userName, string password)
{
  var user = await _context.Users.
}
```

It is not showing me FirstOrDefaultAsync method. I am confused why it is showing me like this ?

Following are the versions I am using for API project -

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.2.2" />
```

Comment: Do you get `FirstOrDefault` method? If you add `var user = _context.Students.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` and `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`, build your project, will you receive any error?

Comment: @Tao Zhou,
It doesn't showing me FirstOrDefault. but I found Add(),AddRange(),Find(),FindAsync() etc.

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? It should exist with `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`.

Comment: Yeah,It works.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You forgot to add the reference  to entity framework core `'using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;'`

Tip: If you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> it should show the immediate fix.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Did you var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync() and hit that  keybind and nothing showed up?

Comment: Yes, I am doing that but I am not find FirstOrDefaultAsync() method.

Comment: Maybe Visual studio bugged out and was unable to track your packages , try to clean your solution close visual studio and reopen it and try to build again and later apply the tip mention in the Answer

Comment: I cleaned Visual Studio Code and reopen project. But still it not showing that method .But it showed me others method but not FirstOrDefault() and FirstOrDefaultAsync()

Answer (score 1):

In case any noobs such as I stumble on this, I simply needed to add:

using System.Linq;

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This would be better suited as a comment not a question. Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Answer (score 0):

> There are not async versions of LINQ operators such as Where(...), OrderBy(...), etc. because these methods only build up the LINQ expression tree and do not cause the query to be executed in the database.

[See in Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async)